# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, publish

I Published a website using VS2012, ASP.NET C#, the publish succeeds however, when i open the .ASPX file, this shows ups:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

Location: file:///E:/Test/Default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 2:
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_bf0k3pjd" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>
-^

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The file location should give a hint. That's a location on the file system and not being passed through a web server. When you view it using file://  then the browser simply displays the contents. The @Page directive in the first line doesn't conform to XML/XHTML/HTML standards so it throws this error. The browser knows nothing about the @Page or anything else in the page except the bits that are HTML. It will still attempt to display all the content, but it really doesn't know what to do with it other than view it as a plain html page. If you run this through an actual web server you shouldn't see this error and the page should be processed properly.

Comment: is there a way i can publish my web application on local-host?

Comment: Install IIS on your computer. You can create a website in IIS (using a different port than 80) and point it to a directory that you can publish your application into.